# Retrieve results from multiple tables in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have three tables `Driver` and `Reservation` and `vehicle`

The table definition

```
    Driver (table)                              Vehicle (table)
    ------------                                ---------------   
    DriverId   varchar (pk)                     VehicleId varchar  (pk)
    DriverName varchar                          VehicleName varchar  


    Reservation (table)
    -------------------                     (pk) --> Primary Key
    ReservationId varchar   (pk)            (fk) --> Foreign Key
    DriverId      varchar   (fk)
    VehicleId     varchar   (fk)
    JourneyDate   Date
```

---

`PoJo Classes`

---

`Driver`

```
@Entity
@Component  
@Table(name="ATA_TBL_DRIVER")
public class DriverBean {

  @Id
  @Column(name="DRIVERID")
  private String driverID;

  @Column(name="NAME")
  private String name;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "driverBean")
  private Set<ReservationBean> reservationBeans;

  // getters and setters
}
```

`VehicleBean`

```
@Entity
@Component
@Table(name="ATA_TBL_VEHICLE")
public class VehicleBean {

   @Id
   @Column(name="VEHICLEID")
   private String vehicleID;

   @Column(name="NAME")
   private String name;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy="vehicleBean")
   private Set<ReservationBean> reservationBeans;

   //getters and setters
}
```

`ReservationBean`

```
@Entity
@Component
@Table(name="ATA_TBL_RESERVATION") 
public class ReservationBean {

   @Id
   @Column(name="RESERVATIONID")
   private String reservationID;    

   @Column(name="JOURNEYDATE")
   private Date journeyDate;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="DRIVERID")
   private DriverBean driverBean;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name="VEHICLEID")
   private VehicleBean vehicleBean;

    //getters and setters
}
```

> ASSUMPTION  :
>   If driverid and vehicleid is present in Reservation table on particular date , means that driver,vehicle is been booked for that date

`Question : I need to query the database for driverid and vehicleid which are not booked on particular journeydate ?`

My Solution to above question was

`Select driverid from ata_tbl_driver where driverid != (select driverid from ata_tbl_reservation where journeydate='21-JAN-15'` for driver. Similary i have done for `vehicle` too in SQLPlus . I got the expected results

But when i run the above query in Hibernate using 
`session.createSQLQuery(Select driverid from ata_tbl_driver where driverid != (select driverid from ata_tbl_reservation where journeydate='21-JAN-15')` , I dont get any results .I dont why ?

Is there any better approach to accomplish the above task. If it is so , Please help.